# How to estimate error rate among 2 similar series?

Tags: matlab

I have a series of numbers `[a1, a2, ..., an]`. These numbers represent speeds that have been collected by a GPS tracker. I additionally have two sets of numbers: The first `[S1, S2, ..., Sn]` represent the distance covered (where S1 is a distance of 0 m and Sn is the total trip distance) and the second `[t1, t2, ..., tn]` represent elapsed time (0 in t1, total time in tn). 
I then compute speed by myself using the formula `v(i) = [S(i+1)-S(i)] / [t(i+1)-t(i)]` with `i from 1 to n-1`

Obviously the values are slightly different. I would know how to use these results to estimate how different are those speeds.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the difference for *every* entry, or trying to come up with some sort of generalized measure of how good your estimates are altogether?

Comment: Might be a better fit for stats.stackexchange.com unless you already know exactly what type of error you want to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolate your GPS "A" vector to match the times of your "V" vector as closely as possible and then take the difference of the vectors by subtracting them.

If you don't want to go to the trouble of interpolating, just chop one element off of your A vector (either the first or last element) and then take the difference of the vectors by subtracting them.

Answer (score 0):

For each `i`, the absolute error is: `abs(a(i)-v(i))`.
It is usually more interesting to look at the relative error that you can define as `abs((a(i)-v(i))/a(i))` or `abs((a(i)-v(i))/v(i))`.

Not sure if it is what you are looking for.